# Micropayments as little as 1p - possible?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I'm looking at accepting payment from as little as 1p.  I know PayPal do micropayments, but they still take 5% plus $0.05, which clearly makes it pointless for me.

Is there a payment gateway that supports such payments, perhaps taking their cut when there is a withdrawl?